# css_selector not returning a list

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium in Python. I used webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('element.class').text to get the text and it returns me the first result (as expected) in the webpage. Everything works fine here.

When i tried, webdriver.find_**elements**_by_css_selector('element.class').text   to return the list of elements from the webpage (as said in the webpage http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html).

I get an error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'**. In principle this should work, i have no idea why this doesn't work. any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `.text` property on a list of `WebElement`s. Instead, you need to call `.text` on every element inside the list:

```
[element.text for element in webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('element.class')]
```